# Show all post of a taxonomy with one specific term not working

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a custom post type "restaurants" and a taxonomy "location", so I can get the restaurants for one location by URL. On the taxonomy page for one specific location (CityA) I want to display all post types from restaurants and the taxonomy term "CityA". However, Wordpress also gives me posts with taxonomy terms "CityB" or "CityC" in the very same query. Have a look:

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'restaurants', 'tax_query' => array ( 'taxonomy' => 'location', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'citya' ), 'order_by' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$query = new WP_Query ( $args );
while ( $query -> have_posts () ) {
    $query -> the_post();
    echo get_permalink($post->ID;
}
```

This gives me ALL posts of post_type "restaurants". And yes, the slug for CityA is definetely "citya", I double checked all arguments.

Comment: You should indent your code properly, as it stands it is hard to read

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters),  you need to use two nested arrays in the `tax_query` argument.

So, with your arguments it should look like this:

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'restaurants', 'tax_query' => array (array( 'taxonomy' => 'location', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'citya') ), 'order_by' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
```

If you only need to query for 1 Term, you can also use the easy way:

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'restaurants', 'location' => 'citya' , 'order_by' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
```